# Overlap of text on SCSS Transitions

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions, css-animations

[CLICK HERE FOR JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/keb8ecLw/)

( WORKS FOR WEB-KIT BROWSERS ONLY )

I am creating a navigation with links that become wider and show text once you hover over them. It all works correctly except for one issue; The text will not vanish quick enough when moving the mouse away from the button and is pushed underneath the button for a split second (and looks very ugly!).

I am struggling to find a solution to this problem, I have tried setting the spans width and height to 0 as well as speed up the transition so the text vanishes quicker, but neither seem to work..

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="items">
        <li>><span class="extra"> View</span>

        </li>
        <li>+<span class="extra"> Add</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" ng-model="typed" />
    </div>
</nav>
```

SCSS:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #dde;

    div {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        padding: 4px 15px 4px 5px;
    }
}

ul#items {
    float: left;

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background-color: #eef;
        color: #99a;
        width: 10px;
        height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.2s linear, color 0.5s linear, background-color 0.5s linear;
    }
    li:hover {
        background-color: #ccd;
        color: #778;
        width: 45px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    li:hover span {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    span {
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-left: 8px 5px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .3s;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually works great for me `Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit)`. What browser are you using?

Comment: Also using chrome, but when you hover out try and notice the text go underneath the > or + symbols on the buttons for a split second.

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.124

Comment: Interesting interaction. If I want to move from the left to the `+`, the `>` button grows and basically pushes away the button that I want to click.

Comment: Have you tried setting  `white-space: nowrap;` on your `#items li`?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `#items li{ white-space: pre; }`, the contents of the li won't wrap, and the label will become visible after the + while growing, and will disappear without a glitch while shrinking.

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/keb8ecLw/42/)

Comment: Thanks! But I ended up opting for the white-space: nowrap; so that I can take overflow: hidden attribute out of the div. :) white-space: pre; made an extra row once the overflow was revealed. http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/keb8ecLw/